# Why is response coming through in Postman working but not my test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, supertest

I have this express controller in order to find the amount of unread notifications, that a user is a recipient of. Here:

```
app.get('/api/user/:uid/notifications/newcount', (req, res, next) => {
    const firebaseUID = req.params.uid;

    User.findOne({ firebaseUID })
      .select('_id')
      .then(user => Notification.count({
          recipients: { $eq: user._id },
          usersRead: { $ne: user._id }
        })
      )
      .then(notificationCount => {
        console.log(notificationCount.toString());
        return res.send(notificationCount.toString())
      })
      .catch(next);
  });
```

This works just fine in postman.

I am trying to test it with Mocha/Supertest. Yet for some reason, the `res.body` always come back as an empty object.

The console logs in the actual controller always come through just fine though.

If I don't send as `toString()` in the `res.send()`, then I get errors.

`res.body` should be coming back as `1`.

How can I grab the `res.body` in the below test in order to make an assertion?

```
it.only('GET to /api/user/firebaseUID/notifications/newcount, gets users unread notifications',
  done => {
      request(app)
        .get(`/api/user/${matt.firebaseUID}/notifications/newcount`)
        .end((err, res) => {
          console.log(res.body);

          done();
        });
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do `res.statusCode` and `res.text` contain when the test fails?

Comment: res.text worked :) thank you

Comment: Why wouldn't it come through in the body?

Comment: `res.body` is used when the response can be processed into a javascript object. So a JSON string in `text` will become a JS object in `body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) module that [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) is based on, the `response.body` property is only populated when the response can be [parsed](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/e46f890fc734bdde3990c13f559436ef48460bd1/lib/client.js#L193-L205) into a Javascript Object. The `response.text` property will include the plain response body as a string.

The [`text` property](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/e46f890fc734bdde3990c13f559436ef48460bd1/lib/client.js#L299-L301) comes from `responseText` in [XMLHttpRequest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest).